# How do i send data from an HTML form to a document?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an HTML page which, after being filled up, needs to collect whatever data the user imputs and place it into a template document, which then needs to be converted into a pdf file and sent to the user to be printed. Does anyone have a tutorial for something similar to this? I have tried to find my way around with php and json files but i keep getting stuck at a certain point and i can't figure out an answer.

Edit: this is an example i've tried, to send stuff into a json file, but all it does is open a webpage with half the code on it:

```
<?php 
       
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
                   
    function get_data() { 
        $name = $_POST['name']; 
        $file_name='StudentsData'. '.json'; 
   
        if(file_exists("$file_name")) {  
            $current_data=file_get_contents("$file_name"); 
            $array_data=json_decode($current_data, true); 
                               
            $extra=array( 
                'Name' => $_POST['name'], 
                'Branch' => $_POST['branch'], 
                'Year' => $_POST['year'], 
            ); 
            $array_data[]=$extra; 
            echo "file exist<br/>"; 
            return json_encode($array_data); 
        } 
        else { 
            $datae=array(); 
            $datae[]=array( 
                'Name' => $_POST['name'], 
                'Branch' => $_POST['branch'], 
                'Year' => $_POST['year'], 
            ); 
            echo "file not exist<br/>"; 
            return json_encode($datae);    
        } 
    } 
  
    $file_name='StudentsData'. '.json'; 
      
    if(file_put_contents("$file_name", get_data())) { 
        echo 'success'; 
    }                 
    else { 
        echo 'There is some error';                 
    } 
} 
       
?>
```

And for clarification, i need whatever fields are being filled, sent to a file, pasted into a template, and that template sent back to the user.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Tutorial for what exactly? There are multiple steps there which can all be learned separately if need be. Be more specific, tell us exactly where you are stuck so far and show the code. P.s. we don't do recommendations for tutorials, you need to do your own research. Instead you can ask us a more detailed question about your own code

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you're seeing PHP code on the screen in your output then it means your code is not being passed through the PHP interpreter and executed. Reasons for that could be: PHP is not installed on your webserver, and/or you're not using a .php extension for the script file, and/or you're loading it into the browser via `file://` instead of via `http://localhost`

Answer (score -1):

I used [fpdf.org](http://www.fpdf.org/) for my website. It's free.

> F from FPDF stands for Free: you may use it for any kind of usage and modify it to suit your needs